# Converting HuggingFace Tokenizer to TensorFlow Keras Layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, huggingface-transformers

I am struggling to understand how to perform inference with a pre-trained HuggingFace model loaded as a TensorFlow Keras model.

**Context**

In my case, I am trying to fine-tune a pre-trained DistilBert classifier. I have something as follows to preprocess my data and load/train my model:

```
from transformers import TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("distilbert-base-uncased")

model = TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(
    "distilbert-base-uncased", num_labels=2, id2label=id2label, label2id=label2id
)

# add another layer

tf_train = model.prepare_tf_dataset(question_train_test_split['train'], batch_size=16, shuffle=True, tokenizer=tokenizer)

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(2e-5))

# freeze the first transformer layer of model

model.layers[0].trainable=False

print('Model Architecture:')
print(model.summary())

model.fit(tf_train, epochs=3)
```

Where `question_train_test_split` is a HuggingFace `Dataset` object instance.

This snippet of code works perfectly as expected, it loads the HuggingFace model as a `tf.keras` layer. This even trains properly with the `.fit` method.

However, I am having issues when I want to perform predictions. I understand that I need to tokenize my string input, however, I would like to load the tokenizer as a `tf.keras` layer. I've looked everywhere for a way to do this and I was not able to find any way.

Ideally, I would like something like this:

```
user_input = 'When were the Beatles formed?'

model_input = tokenizer(user_input) # THIS HF TOKENIZER SHOULD BE A tf.keras LAYER

model = model(model_input)
```

This is so that I can save the entire model (with the tokenizer and the transformer layers + the classifier layers) into a TensorFlow SavedModel. If there's any pointers out there to convert a HuggingFace tokenizer into a TensorFlow Keras layer, I would appreciate the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

In hugging face documentation you can use the tokenizer to tokenizer your text and return tensorflow tensors. you can do something as follows:

```
tokenized_outputs = tokenizer(user_input, return_tensors = 'tf')
```

This indicates that you want to return tensorflow type tensors. You can chose PyTorch tensors by typing `'pt'` instead of `'tf'`

For more information checkout the documentation [here](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/tokenizer#transformers.PreTrainedTokenizer.__call__.return_tensors).

you can also use the function TFAutoModel in transformers to retrieve models in tensorflow format.

Hope this helps